# Skip empty Textboxes in a Loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I got a working Code and need to apply it to all my records at my continous form.

```
Private Sub Befehl104_Click()

 While Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount

      Me.WreckBreiteDD.Value = Round(WechselnD(Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value), 7)
     Me.WreckLängeDD.Value = Round(WechselnD(Me.WreckLängeDMS.Value), 7)


DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNext
Wend
End Sub
```

Sometimes the "WreckBreiteDMS" is empty, so the code stops because the function "WechselnD" cant be executes.

How can I skip those empty Textboxes?

Already tried  "Nz()" at all possible places, nothing helped.

I think i need to do something like:

```
 If Me.WreckBreiteDD.Value = Round(WechselnD(Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value), 7) = 0, DoCmd.GoToRecord:=acNext
```

But I got some problems with the snytax..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples where
`WreckLängeDMS` is string, and
`WreckBreiteDMS` is numeric

```vb
Private Sub Befehl104_Click()

 While Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount

     if not isnull(Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value) then
         Me.WreckBreiteDD.Value = Round(WechselnD(Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value), 7)
     end if
     if nz(Me.WreckLängeDMS.Value,"")<>"" then
         Me.WreckLängeDD.Value = Round(WechselnD(Me.WreckLängeDMS.Value), 7)
     end if


DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNext
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

use `len` on the string (in your case: Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value) in the if statement. remove the rest from the if statement.

```
If Len(Nz(Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value)) > 0 Then
    Me.WreckBreiteDD.Value = Round(WechselnD(Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value), 7)
End If
```

Comment: There is no `Continue` statement in VBA though, so the nesting is inevitable. Also `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is a .NET thing. This is VBA, not VB.NET.

Comment: I could tell :) ...the `Then` keyword and block nature of the conditional is what the OP needs though.

Comment: That should work, though I'm not familiar with Access and I *think* `If Len(Nz(Me.WreckBreiteDMS.Value, vbNullString)) > 0 Then` would safely handle a `Null` value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that

Comment: Unfortunatly not working, but thanks for your effort